# Why Am I Getting Deadlock - Please Read Trace

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, deadlock

can anyone help me?
i'm getting deadlock on this trace, i'm using symmetricds and i can't understand why i'm getting a deadlock on a certain table.

I'm using sql server 2008 r2, read_committed_snapshot is turned on.
The table has one clustered index and it is on node_id

I don't know why I'm getting deadlock, can anyone explain the trace file?

```
waiter id=process1f53674c8 mode=U requestType=wait
waiter-list
owner id=process2200f5948 mode=U
owner-list
keylock hobtid=72057594175946752 dbid=19 objectname=tester-prd-tester-main.dbo.sym_node indexname=PK__sym_node__5F19EF1676C4B313 id=lock1a3f14e80 mode=U associatedObjectId=72057594175946752
waiter id=process2200f5948 mode=U requestType=wait
waiter-list
owner id=process1f53674c8 mode=X
owner-list
keylock hobtid=72057594175946752 dbid=19 objectname=tester-prd-tester-main.dbo.sym_node indexname=PK__sym_node__5F19EF1676C4B313 id=lock250b1cb00 mode=X associatedObjectId=72057594175946752
resource-list
(@P0 nvarchar(4000)<c/>@P1 nvarchar(4000)<c/>@P2 nvarchar(4000)<c/>@P3 int<c/>@P4 nvarchar(4000)<c/>@P5 nvarchar(4000)<c/>@P6 nvarchar(4000)<c/>@P7 nvarchar(4000)<c/>@P8 nvarchar(4000)<c/>@P9 datetime<c/>@P10 nvarchar(4000)<c/>@P11 int<c/>@P12 int<c/>@P13 nvarchar(4000)<c/>@P14 nvarchar(4000))update dbo.sym_node set "node_id" =  @P0 <c/> "node_group_id" =  @P1 <c/> "external_id" =  @P2 <c/> "sync_enabled" =  @P3 <c/> "sync_url" =  @P4 <c/> "schema_version" =  @P5 <c/> "symmetric_version" =  @P6 <c/> "database_type" =  @P7 <c/> "database_version" =  @P8 <c/> "heartbeat_time" =  @P9 <c/> "timezone_offset" =  @P10 <c/> "batch_to_send_count" =  @P11 <c/> "batch_in_error_count" =  @P12 <c/> "created_at_node_id" =  @P13  where "node_id" =  @P14
inputbuf
update dbo.sym_node set "node_id" =  @P0 <c/> "node_group_id" =  @P1 <c/> "external_id" =  @P2 <c/> "sync_enabled" =  @P3 <c/> "sync_url" =  @P4 <c/> "schema_version" =  @P5 <c/> "symmetric_version" =  @P6 <c/> "database_type" =  @P7 <c/> "database_version" =  @P8 <c/> "heartbeat_time" =  @P9 <c/> "timezone_offset" =  @P10 <c/> "batch_to_send_count" =  @P11 <c/> "batch_in_error_count" =  @P12 <c/> "created_at_node_id" =  @P13  where "node_id" =  @P14
frame procname=adhoc line=1 stmtstart=504 sqlhandle=0x020000007430040fc90acec8b230d13e24f8efc99977f395
executionStack
process id=process1f53674c8 taskpriority=0 logused=1488 waitresource=KEY: 19:72057594175946752 (fb992e63ce7c) waittime=4927 ownerId=5484183322 transactionname=implicit_transaction lasttranstarted=2012-11-28T19:47:10.653 XDES=0xb08a83b0 lockMode=U schedulerid=11 kpid=7984 status=suspended spid=3683 sbid=0 ecid=0 priority=0 trancount=2 lastbatchstarted=2012-11-28T19:47:11.647 lastbatchcompleted=2012-11-28T19:47:11.647 clientapp=jTDS hostname=clienttesterAPP hostpid=123 loginname=tester-PRD-tester-MAIN isolationlevel=read committed (2) xactid=5484183322 currentdb=19 lockTimeout=4294967295 clientoption1=671088672 clientoption2=128058
(@P0 nvarchar(4000)<c/>@P1 nvarchar(4000)<c/>@P2 nvarchar(4000)<c/>@P3 int<c/>@P4 nvarchar(4000)<c/>@P5 nvarchar(4000)<c/>@P6 nvarchar(4000)<c/>@P7 nvarchar(4000)<c/>@P8 nvarchar(4000)<c/>@P9 datetime<c/>@P10 nvarchar(4000)<c/>@P11 int<c/>@P12 int<c/>@P13 nvarchar(4000)<c/>@P14 nvarchar(4000))update dbo.sym_node set "node_id" =  @P0 <c/> "node_group_id" =  @P1 <c/> "external_id" =  @P2 <c/> "sync_enabled" =  @P3 <c/> "sync_url" =  @P4 <c/> "schema_version" =  @P5 <c/> "symmetric_version" =  @P6 <c/> "database_type" =  @P7 <c/> "database_version" =  @P8 <c/> "heartbeat_time" =  @P9 <c/> "timezone_offset" =  @P10 <c/> "batch_to_send_count" =  @P11 <c/> "batch_in_error_count" =  @P12 <c/> "created_at_node_id" =  @P13  where "node_id" =  @P14
inputbuf
update dbo.sym_node set "node_id" =  @P0 <c/> "node_group_id" =  @P1 <c/> "external_id" =  @P2 <c/> "sync_enabled" =  @P3 <c/> "sync_url" =  @P4 <c/> "schema_version" =  @P5 <c/> "symmetric_version" =  @P6 <c/> "database_type" =  @P7 <c/> "database_version" =  @P8 <c/> "heartbeat_time" =  @P9 <c/> "timezone_offset" =  @P10 <c/> "batch_to_send_count" =  @P11 <c/> "batch_in_error_count" =  @P12 <c/> "created_at_node_id" =  @P13  where "node_id" =  @P14
frame procname=adhoc line=1 stmtstart=504 sqlhandle=0x020000007430040fc90acec8b230d13e24f8efc99977f395
executionStack
process id=process2200f5948 taskpriority=0 logused=488 waitresource=KEY: 19:72057594175946752 (303c5a46f094) waittime=4972 ownerId=5484183543 transactionname=implicit_transaction lasttranstarted=2012-11-28T19:47:11.230 XDES=0x283e0b950 lockMode=U schedulerid=22 kpid=6320 status=suspended spid=3581 sbid=0 ecid=0 priority=0 trancount=2 lastbatchstarted=2012-11-28T19:47:11.543 lastbatchcompleted=2012-11-28T19:47:11.543 clientapp=jTDS hostname=clienttesterAPP hostpid=123 loginname=tester-PRD-tester-MAIN isolationlevel=read committed (2) xactid=5484183543 currentdb=19 lockTimeout=4294967295 clientoption1=671088672 clientoption2=128058
process-list
deadlock victim=process2200f5948
deadlock-list
ResType:LockOwner Stype:'OR'Xdes:0x0000000283E0B950 Mode: U SPID:3581 BatchID:0 ECID:0 TaskProxy:(0x00000000EE40C538) Value:0xdc87ce80 Cost:(0/488)
Victim Resource Owner:
Log Viewer could not read information for this log entry. Cause: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.. Content:
ResType:LockOwner Stype:'OR'Xdes:0x00000000B08A83B0 Mode: U SPID:3683 BatchID:0 ECID:0 TaskProxy:(0x00000002E1E62538) Value:0x5ae0b9c0 Cost:(0/1488)
Requested by:
Input Buf: Language Event: (@P0 nvarchar(4000)<c/>@P1 nvarchar(4000)<c/>@P2 nvarchar(4000)<c/>@P3 int<c/>@P4 nvarchar(4000)<c/>@P5 nvarchar(4000)<c/>@P6 nvarchar(4000)<c/>@P7 nvarchar(4000)<c/>@P8 nvarchar(4000)<c/>@P9 datetime<c/>@P10 nvarchar(4000)<c/>@P11 int<c/>@P12 int<c/>@P13 nvarchar(4000)<c/>@P14 nvarchar(4000))upd
SPID: 3581 ECID: 0 Statement Type: UPDATE Line #: 1
Owner:0x000000026872AC80 Mode: U        Flg:0x40 Ref:0 Life:00000001 SPID:3581 ECID:0 XactLockInfo: 0x0000000283E0B990
Grant List 2:
KEY: 19:72057594175946752 (fb992e63ce7c) CleanCnt:2 Mode:U Flags: 0x1
Node:2
Log Viewer could not read information for this log entry. Cause: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.. Content:
ResType:LockOwner Stype:'OR'Xdes:0x0000000283E0B950 Mode: U SPID:3581 BatchID:0 ECID:0 TaskProxy:(0x00000000EE40C538) Value:0xdc87ce80 Cost:(0/488)
Requested by:
Input Buf: Language Event: (@P0 nvarchar(4000)<c/>@P1 nvarchar(4000)<c/>@P2 nvarchar(4000)<c/>@P3 int<c/>@P4 nvarchar(4000)<c/>@P5 nvarchar(4000)<c/>@P6 nvarchar(4000)<c/>@P7 nvarchar(4000)<c/>@P8 nvarchar(4000)<c/>@P9 datetime<c/>@P10 nvarchar(4000)<c/>@P11 int<c/>@P12 int<c/>@P13 nvarchar(4000)<c/>@P14 nvarchar(4000))upd
SPID: 3683 ECID: 0 Statement Type: UPDATE Line #: 1
Owner:0x000000025A793580 Mode: X        Flg:0x40 Ref:0 Life:02000000 SPID:3683 ECID:0 XactLockInfo: 0x00000000B08A83F0
Grant List 1:
KEY: 19:72057594175946752 (303c5a46f094) CleanCnt:2 Mode:X Flags: 0x1
Node:1
Log Viewer could not read information for this log entry. Cause: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.. Content:
Wait-for graph
Deadlock encountered .... Printing deadlock information
```

Comment: Can you upload the .xdl file somewhere? Also useful would be the queries on either side and any other context (eg are they part of a larger transaction)? I have no idea what symmetricds is so if there is any detail about that that might be important, I'm not sure how many people here will be able to suss it out.